# Highest value in row in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Could anyone enlighten how we can retrieve the highest value of row using MySQL

For example I have below data in table

```
A    B   C   D
3    6   8   10
```

I would like retrieve the from the row

MAX() is acceptable for columns as per my understanding

Hope this is more clear now.

```
R1 R2 R3 R4 R5 
10D 9D 8D 7D 6D
```

The above data in the table. Ideally I should get a 10D as the greatest but when i execute this query. Select GREATEST(R1, R2, R3, R4, R5) from TableAA I got the output as 9D. Can someone please explain the logic that I got 9D as the greatest.

Comment: Did you look at `MAX()`

Comment: I don't understand the question do you mean the row with the highest value for a specific column?

Comment: And do you mean Column rather than Row

Comment: `SELECT GREATEST(A,B,C,D)`

Comment: R1     R2    R3   R4   R5
10D   9D   8D   7D   6D

The above data in the table.
Ideally I should get a 10D as the greatest but when i execute this quey.
select GREATEST(R1, R2, R3, R4, R5) from TableAA

I got the output as 9D. Can someone please explain the logic that I got 9D as the greatest.

Comment: You can check this answer from dba for some suggestions. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/116369/highest-value-of-a-row-in-mysql

Comment: Also, if you are comparing strings, `'9'` is greater than `'10'`, because it starts with character "9". Try these two queries:
`select greatest(9, 10);`
`select greatest('9', '10');`

Comment: Thanks all. now i got it.

Comment: It is rather uncommon to have values in one row you'd want to sum up. This *may* indicate a poor data model where it would be better to store these values in separate rows. It is also rather uncommon to want to sort alphanumeric strings by some special sort order. If you want to sort by the leading number, then by the string, this may again indicate a poor data model, where you should have separate columns for the number and the string. Maybe you even need another table holding all allowed values with an additional sortkey (this is typical for instance for sizes S, M, L, XL, XXL, 3XL, 4XL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `GREATEST('Def', 'Abc', '0ab')` it sorts the text values in lexical (dictionary) order and takes the greatest one. Your values like `9A` and `10B` are also text strings, and the first one comes after the second one in lexical order. §

GREATEST() on a bunch of numbers does what you expect.

MySql has a hack where you can convert text strings with leading numbers to actual numbers. Add `0` to the string. `0+'10D'` gets you the number `10`.

So to get what you want, try

```
GREATEST(0+R1, 0+R2, 0+R3, 0+R4, 0+R5)
```

And beware, this `0+` hack doesn't work on other makes and models of database server.

§ it doesn't actually sort them, it searches for the the greatest value, but in lexical, not numeric, order.

Comment: @AnyLuck: While this query may solve your problem, your *real* problem may be your data model and if so you may want to change that rather than circumvent the issue in every other query. Please see my comment under your request on this.